# How to graph $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-2x}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2+x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I plot the following function by hand without using the aid of a computer?

$$\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-2x}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2+x^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all one can notice that
$$-2x\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{\pi ^2 (2 k+1)^2+x^2}=-2x\frac{\tanh \frac{x}{2} }{2 x}=-\tanh \frac{x}{2}$$